# Why is a "non-single-group group function" allowed in a subselect but not on it's own?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Why does the first query not fail with the same error as the second:

```
with w as (select 1 product_id, 10 units from dual union all select 2, 5 from dual)
select sum(units) from (select product_id, sum(units) units from w);

/*
SUM(UNITS)
----------
        15 
*/

with w as (select 1 product_id, 10 units from dual union all select 2, 5 from dual)
select product_id, sum(units) units from w;

/*
Error starting at line 7 in command:
with w as (select 1 product_id, 10 units from dual union all select 2, 5 from dual)
select product_id, sum(units) units from w
Error at Command Line:8 Column:8
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
*/
```

edit: version info added:

```
select * from v$version;
/*
BANNER                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production                        
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production                                           
CORE    11.2.0.3.0  Production                                                         
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production                                   
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production                 
*/
```

edit: non-default params added:

```
select name, value from v$parameter where isdefault = 'FALSE' order by name;
/*
NAME                              VALUE                                                                                                                             
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aq_tm_processes                   1                                                                                                                                 
archive_lag_target                3600                                                                                                                              
audit_file_dest                   /u01/app/oracle/admin/oracle/adump                                                                                                
audit_trail                       NONE                                                                                                                              
compatible                        11.2.0.3                                                                                                                          
control_file_record_keep_time     31                                                                                                                                
control_files                     /home/oracle/cfile/controlfile.dat, +DATA/oracle/controlfile/current.915.730988607, +FRA/oracle/controlfile/current.970.730988607 
core_dump_dest                    /u01/app/oracle/admin/oracle/cdump                                                                                                
db_block_size                     4096                                                                                                                              
db_create_file_dest               +DATA                                                                                                                             
db_domain                                                                                                                                                           
db_file_multiblock_read_count     1                                                                                                                                 
db_name                           oracle                                                                                                                            
db_recovery_file_dest             +FRA                                                                                                                              
db_recovery_file_dest_size        375809638400                                                                                                                      
diagnostic_dest                   /u01/app/oracle                                                                                                                   
dispatchers                       (PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=oracleXDB)                                                                                                
event                                                                                                                                                               
filesystemio_options              setall                                                                                                                            
global_names                      TRUE                                                                                                                              
job_queue_processes               10                                                                                                                                
log_archive_dest_1                                                                                                                                                  
log_archive_dest_10               LOCATION=USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST MANDATORY REOPEN=60                                                                            
log_checkpoint_timeout            30                                                                                                                                
memory_max_target                 36507222016                                                                                                                       
memory_target                     36507222016                                                                                                                       
nls_language                      ENGLISH                                                                                                                           
nls_length_semantics              BYTE                                                                                                                              
nls_territory                     UNITED KINGDOM                                                                                                                    
open_cursors                      300                                                                                                                               
pga_aggregate_target              0                                                                                                                                 
processes                         150                                                                                                                               
remote_login_passwordfile         EXCLUSIVE                                                                                                                         
sga_max_size                      32212254720                                                                                                                       
sga_target                        0                                                                                                                                 
shared_pool_size                  536870912                                                                                                                         
smtp_out_server                   mailout.redacted.com                                                                                                                   
streams_pool_size                 1073741824                                                                                                                        
undo_management                   AUTO                                                                                                                              
undo_retention                    900                                                                                                                               
undo_tablespace                   TS_UNDO                                                                                                                           

 41 rows selected
*/
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a small dataset on sql fiddle?

Comment: I guess it's a bug in Oracle11 parser/optimizer (it's probably too smart and ignores  `product_id` in inline view) . Both of them fail in Oracle10g ("not a single-group group function").

Comment: @Jack What patch level are you on?

Comment: @Phil [SQLFiddle gives the same](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9708) odd result (it's 11.2.0.2 XE, I'm on 11.2.0.3 SE 64bit Linux)

Comment: @a1ex07 I'm sure you are right it's an optimizer bug: `select sum(units), avg(product_id) from (select product_id, sum(units) units from w);` fails as expected.

Comment: I noticed this myself the other day running 11.2.0.3.4

Comment: @Chris I think I've noticed it before too, but this is the first time I tried to come up with a minimal demo.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's a bug in your Oracle version.

- In `11.1.0.7.0`, `9.2.0.7.0` and `11.2.0.3.0`:

  ```
  SQL> with w as (
    2  SELECT 1 product_id, 10 units FROM dual
    3  UNION ALL
    4  SELECT 2, 5 FROM dual)
    5  SELECT SUM(units) FROM (SELECT product_id, SUM(units) units FROM w);

  ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
  ```

The subquery is definitely **not** valid. There may be a simplification made by the optimizer in merging the two aggregate queries (as suggested by [@a1ex07](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2232/a1ex07)), but the merge shouldn't take place in any case since the query is not logically correct.

There are several bugs regarding incorrect `GROUP BY` behaviour logged in MOS, but I couldn't find one that looks exactly this this one. The closest I found is [Bug 8945974](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=8945974) where an incorrect query with a `GROUP BY` was working in `10.2.0.3` and patching the database to `10.2.0.4` made it appropriately fail.

Comment: Is your 11.2 64-bit Linux like mine?

Comment: Yes, it's from the [apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com) demo website. **Exactly** the same `v$version` info!

Comment: Very odd. Any significant differences to my `select name, value from v$parameter where isdefault = 'FALSE' order by name;`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to this view on that instance.

Comment: btw the `no_merge` and `materialize` hints don't make any difference. I think technically it is eliminating the unused column rather than merging the queries but I guess the bug is that it doesn't throw a parse error first.

Comment: Which PSU of `11.2.0.3` are you on? I see the incorrect behaviour on `11.2.0.3.4`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the query optimiser is applying a transformation to your first query that eliminates product_id from the inline view, then merging the inline view into the main query to that it executes as:

```
with w as (select 1 product_id, 10 units from dual union all select 2, 5 from dual)
select sum(units) from w;
```

Actually, it probably then transforms it further to:

```
select sum(units) from (select 10 units from dual union all select 5 from dual);
```

Comment: Your two examples share the same plan (see [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9767) and [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9768)) but my original has a [different plan](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9708), and using the `no_merge` or `materialize` doesn't make any difference, which is why I think the CBO is eliminating product_id from the inline view but not merging the inline view into the main query.